# Why FullCalendar is not showing properly?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

```js
//example data for events

[
  {
    "jobId": 0,
    "eventId": 79,
    "title": "<b>2018-07-31 00029 Markosy Postal S.A.<\/b><br><span class='eventComment'>asfdasfsd<\/span>",
    "start": "\/Date(1533542400000)\/",
    "end": "\/Date(1533551400000)\/",
    "color": "#FFCC00"
  },
  {
    "jobId": 0,
    "eventId": 80,
    "title": "<b>2018-07-31 00029 Markosy Postal S.A.<\/b><br><span class='eventComment'>sfsdgs<\/span>",
    "start": "\/Date(1533637800000)\/",
    "end": "\/Date(1533646800000)\/",
    "color": "#FFCC00"
  },
  {
    "jobId": 0,
    "eventId": 81,
    "title": "<b>2018-07-31 00029 Markosy Postal S.A.<\/b><br><span class='eventComment'>dfdf s ddfsda ds fds  2222<\/span>",
    "start": "\/Date(1533722400000)\/",
    "end": "\/Date(1533727800000)\/",
    "color": "#FFCC00"
  },
  {
    "jobId": 0,
    "eventId": 84,
    "title": "<b>2018-07-31 00029 Markosy Postal S.A.<\/b><br><span class='eventComment'>gdgdfgsd<\/span>",
    "start": "\/Date(1533808800000)\/",
    "end": "\/Date(1533812400000)\/",
    "color": "#FFCC00"
  }
]
```

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 locale: 'pl',
 defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,listWeek,year'
 },
 height: 'auto',
 footer: false,
 weekends: false,
 slotEventOverlap: false,
 timezone: 'local',
 editable: true,
 selectable: true,
 events: {
  url: '@Url.Action("GetGraphicCalendarEvents", "Schedule")',
  textColor: 'black'
 },
 eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
  var title = element.find('.fc-title, .fc-list-item-title');
  title.html(title.text());
 },
 eventDrop: function (event) {
  updateEventDate(event);
 },
 eventResize: function (event) {
  updateEventDate(event);
 },
 select: function (startDate, endDate) {
  $.ajax({
   url: "@Url.Action("GraphicCalendarAddView", "Schedule")",
   type: "post",
   data: {
    orderId: $("#OrderId").val(),
    start: startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
    end: endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
   },
   success: function (result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty("Success") && !result.Success) {
     //error
    } else {
     //success
    }
   },
   error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
    //error
   }

  });
 },
 eventClick: function (event) {
  updateEventView(event);
 }
});
```

I have a problem with FullCalendar https://fullcalendar.io/docs, I add some screenshot to explain my problem, When i click the button to show my calendar, but I only see not properly loaded events in calendar and when I click on any buttons of drag this thin strips it get fixed and calendar show everything properly.

[image: picture 1(thin strip )]

[image: picture 2(calendar show everything properly)]

Comment: without code and sample data, how can we possibly tell you what you did wrong? It's like asking us to fix a picture of the smoke coming from your car, without seeing the car. Please give us sufficient information to reproduce your problem so we can understand it. Then we will be happy to help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: As requested, please provide some sample event data. As-is, this still cannot be reproduced. Also, from the screenshot it appears you have customised the CSS or added extra CSS rules which would affect fullCalendar. So please show that as well. Custom CSS is a common cause of layout and presentation issues.

Comment: I don't use any extra CSS file,I must add that FullCalendar is viewed in pop-up but I think it's not causing this?

Comment: Here is Codepen with this bug: https://codepen.io/mpysz/pen/djwwpv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution , the modal is not rendered, when the calendar is being rendered, I must add some delay.

example code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKPyEN?editors=0010

```js
 $(function() {
  
     $(".graphicPlanninngLetter").on("click", function() {
    openCalendarWithView("GraphicPlanning");
    });

    function openCalendarWithView(action) {
    showPopup("Test", "<div id='calendar'></div>");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        locale: 'pl',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,listWeek,year'
        },
        allDaySlot: false,
        height: 'auto',
        footer: false,
        weekends: false,
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        timezone: 'local',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
          var title = element.find('.fc-title, .fc-list-item-title');
          title.html(title.text());
        },
      });
    }, 300)
    }

    function showPopup(title, content, button, selector) {
    if (selector == undefined)
      selector = "#popup";
    $(selector + " .popupTitle").html(title);
    $(selector + " .popupBody").html(content);
    $(selector + " .popupButtons .additionalButtons").empty().append(button);
    $(selector).modal("show");
    }
  
    });
```

Comment: `timezone: 'local',` solved my timezone related issue. Thanks Magda98.